# Create a binding to save with `shift S S` in vim

Tags: linux, unix, vim

Recently someone recommended I save in vim using shift Z Z. This is working great for me! How can I create a shortcut so that shift S S maps to `:w`?

Comment: Like what can be shorter than one key command (`:w`)? Do you want something with zero keys? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save in insert mode (VIM)](http://superuser.com/questions/88432/save-in-insert-mode-vim)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy shift ZZ is feels faster than `:x`. Similarly, shift S S would feel faster that `:w`

Comment: OK, it's up to you. I was never thinking I would need anything else than `:w`. So just map any key you want to that command and you'll have single-key save.

Comment: Cool. I'm changing my question to reflect with.

Comment: But why do you like the `shift S S` "shortcut"? Why not for example `F2` or something similar? Originally you requested the fastest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute this line in last line mode, or put it in your .vimrc

```
:map <S-s><S-s> :w<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally you were asking for that fastest way to save. I would say that it can be this alias:

```
inoremap <F2> <c-o>:w<cr>
```

It creates an alias for <kbd>F2</kbd> key which executes the command `:w`. You can use whichever other key you want instead of <kbd>F2</kbd> of course. And you can put it to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I'm on a mac - pressing the f2 key is an awkward combo of fn+f2

Comment: So why would you use `F2`? Use whichever key you want.

Comment: In my experience most key bindings are already taken

Comment: zz isn't taken...

Comment: @jdk1.0 zz is taken to scroll the line you are currently on to the center of the screen