# vim create a binding so that pressing "Shift I I" writes python import statements

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, unix, vim

I want to create a binding so that pressing "Shift I I" writes python import statements.

I think it should be a map, like [this](https://superuser.com/a/1045627/456097):

`:map <S-i><S-i> ...`

I'm not sure how to map my desired output. I want to enter insert mode, then type:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

My issue is that I do not know how to insert the return character in this mapping. This mapping works, but only produces one line:

`:map <S-i><S-i> iimport numpy as np`

I tried using a return character,

`:map <S-i><S-i> iimport numpy as np\nimoprt pandas as pd`

but that didn't work. It just writes the return character out.

I also tried entering a space in the file,

```
imoprt pandas as pd:map <S-i><S-i> iimport numpy as np
imoprt pandas as pd
```

but that yields the error

```
Error detected while processing /Users/kilojoules/.vimrc:
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: imoprt pandas as pd
```

How can I make this mapping write out the desired import statements?

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT gave a nice answer:

> To insert a newline character in a Vim mapping, you can use the `<CR>`
> symbol. You can use this symbol to create your desired mapping as
> follows:
>
> ```
> :map <S-i><S-i> iimport numpy as np<CR>import pandas as pd<CR>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt<CR>
> ```
>
> This will create a mapping that inserts the import statements when you
> press Shift+i twice.